# Interacting with Electron via HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

Excuse the stupid question, but I'm super new to Electron and kind of lost.

This is basically what my project looks like:

`package.json`:

```
...
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron ."
}
...
```

`index.html`:

```
...
<script src="mystuff.js"></script>
...
```

How can I, for example, run something like `window.maximize()` from `mystuff.js`? Do I need to include it somewhere before the page loads? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the render process you can access the current window using the Electron `remote` API:

```
let window = require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

If you need access to the window from the main process, a reference to the window is created when you open it.

Comment: Could you dumb it down for me a little? Like a step by step process? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

--`mystuff.js`--

```
var win= require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

And you can maximize it by doing

```
win.maximize();
```